# Table Transpose in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the most efficient way to transpose the table below in SQL Server? I could do it using `case` statements, however that is not what I am looking for.

```
County  Total
--------------
US      $625 
CA      $160 
GB      $0 
AU      $0
```

Expected output:

```
US      CA      GB  AU
------------------------
$625    $160    $0  $0
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to `transpose` the data in `Sql Server` is by using [**`PIVOT`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) keyword

```
SELECT US,
       CA,
       GB,
       AU
FROM   Yourtable
       PIVOT (Max(total)
             FOR county IN (US,
                            CA,
                            GB,
                            AU)) pv
```